# How to delete or modify hooks with Bitbucket API? I only see GET and POST

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api

https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/hooks

I only see GET and POST verbs for hook events on Bitbucket. Is there a way to delete or modify them somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Just append `/{uid}` after `/hooks`, and you get actions to operate on individual ones. See https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/hooks/%7Buid%7D for documentation on them.